# autoconf and sysvinit/systemd etc

Tags: linux, init, autoconf, m4

A constant problem I run into with `autoconf` is init scripts.  The whole point of `autoconf` is of course portability, and the various init systems (sysvinit, systemd, upstart) - not to mention various differences between the same init system on different distros (like `/etc/init.d` vs `/etc/rc.d/` vs `/etc/rc.d/init.d`) - are crying out for a portable start/stop script solution.

I thought that *someone* would have created a nice m4 macro by now that handles this, but I can't find one.

This is strange because it seems like a common problem, and they even have m4 macros now to detect much newer issues like C++11 compatibility and other things.

So, before I roll up my sleeves and spend the time to make a (hopefully) decent m4 macro that tries to determine what init system to use, I'd be interested in knowing if someone else has already done it better.  I can't seem to find anything on Google - and I've even read posts where people actually *discourage* using `autoconf` to install init scripts.  Personally, I think that sentiment is simply impractical - users these days are used to package managers automatically installing init scripts, so there's no reason that you shouldn't get the same when compiling from source.

So, is there already a good m4 macro that handles this, or should I spend the time to write my own?

Comment: I'm confused, what are you asking for?  Exactly what do you mean by _portable start/stop script solution_?  Also, have you written a _working_ init script before?  Do you want something that helps write init scripts or helps install them or helps make it so that they are portable from one init system to another?  More importantly, how do you run into a problem with init scripts while using `autoconf`?  I understand that you're trying to find a way to write _write once, use anywhere_ init scripts, but... how does `autoconf` fit in aside from it using `m4`?